# how do i solve my python file not working

Tags: python, html, mysql

sorry I'm still learning
I want to overcome the error I'm experiencing, namely my python file doesn't want to run when I run it, may I know what's the solution?

here my python code:

```
# Define route for login page
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

# Define route for handling login request
@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    mesage = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = % s AND password = % s', (username, password, ))
        user = cursor.fetchone()
        if user:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['email'] = user['email']
            mesage = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return redirect('profile.html', mesage = mesage)
        else:
            mesage = 'Please enter correct email / password !'
    return render_template('login.html', mesage = mesage)
```

with the following html file:

```
      <img src="../static/assets/Asset 44.svg" class="img-fluid rounded-top" id="logo" alt="">
      {% if mesage is defined and mesage %}
                  <div class="alert alert-warning">{{ mesage }}</div>
            {% endif %}
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form action="{{ url_for('login_post') }}" method="post">
        <div class="txt_field">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
          <span></span>
          <label for="username">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="txt_field">
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
          <span></span>
          <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="pass">Forgot Password?</div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
        <div class="signup_link">
          Not a member? <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Daftar</a>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted (if there is no other code you omitted) is not running because there is nothing to run - you only defined the functions, but there is nothing to execute them.

If you are using flask, you need to first create the app and then start the app, like this:

```
from flask import Flask
 
app = Flask(__name__) # create a new flask app

# Define your routes here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```